# Trigger that creates a custom object record on the first of every month?

Tags: trigger, time-dependent-workflow

I'm trying to write a trigger that creates a custom object record on the first of every month.

So, essentially, I want the trigger to fire:

```
trigger CreateCustObjRecord on Object()
{
    Date current = Date.today(); 
    if(current.day = 1) 
    {
        Object custObj = new Object();
        Object.Name = 'New Custom Object';
        Object.CreationDate = current;
        insert custObj; 
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how ot make this trigger fire. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that would be a better fit for scheduled apex - this will allow you to execute some code according to a date/time schedule.  You can schedule the job from the UI or from code, via the developer console.

Take a look at the docs at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

There's a blog post at:

http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2012/05/26/scheduled-actions-in-salesforce-with-apex/

that includes an example of executing code on the first of every month.

Answer (score 4):

Triggers only fire when a record is created, modified or deleted. You can't use triggers to fire at a certain time. You should create a scheduled job. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm.

The code would look something like this (untested):

```
global class CreateCustObjRecord implements Schedulable{

    global void execute (SchedulableContext SC) {
        Object custObj = new Object();
        Object.Name = 'New Custom Object';
        Object.CreationDate = current;
        insert custObj;   
    }
}
```

You then schedule it by clicking "Schedule Apex" in the Setup->Develop->Apex Classes